# Is it possible to limit use of 3rd party libraries within own solution?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to limit the use of 3rd party libraries such as NewtonSoft or AutoMapper when you want to add them to your own widely used libraries?

E.g. Let's say we have a class library that several other projects use for some arbitrary thing, this library in turn uses another 3rd party library.
This will of course require all other projects that -only- want to use our own project to also reference NewtonSoft or AutoMapper whether it needs it or not.

Is there a way to build around this somehow (other than the obvious part, not using 3rd party libraries)?

**EDIT**

Let's say I have a web project A, that need to reference my business logic in a class library B, the class library uses AutoMapper, I would like a way to not have to reference AutoMapper in project A. I believe this is not possible but if it is I would like to know how.

It would solve issues like if project A and C use different versions of the same library it would conflict, I know this can get sorted in webconfig by explicitly stating which version to use. But if there is a cleaner way I would like to know how.

**EDIT # 2**

What if I marked the area that uses AutoMapper in class library B as **internal** for instance? there would be no need for a reference to AutoMapper in project A, right?

Could that work?

Comment: Put the NewtonSoftware and/or AutoMapper code in a different namespace.  So when other projects use code they don't have to reference the namespace(s) with the 3rd party dll.

Comment: If you don't want consumers of your library to require Automapper, then don't make your library dependent on Automapper.

Comment: I'm looking right now at Project A which references a Project B which uses Json.Net. Project A **does not** have a reference to NewtonSoft.Json, but works just fine.

Comment: This is a classical transitive requirement. If B requires Json.Net and A requires B, then A also requires Json.Net (indirectly via B). Same way you need .NET core the run either project in the first place.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to do, you shouldn't need to reference something that is exclusively used by one project in every project in your solution.  Maybe if you said Why you were trying to do this it might make more sense?

Comment: Doesn't nuget solve this problem? Or at least make it easy?

Comment: For your edit. Lets say the client calls `Foo()` on your library, then `Foo()` calls a `internal class Bar { public T MyMap<T>(object source) { return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<T>(source); } }`. If the client executable does not have `Automapper.dll` in its output directory what do you expect to happen when `Mapper.Map<T>(source);` is called on the internal class?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain very true, that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split up your library. One part (A) uses Newtonsoft and AutoMapper, the other part (B) does not.

Probably A will have a dependency to B.

All other projects can decide if to use A or B. If they requiere functionality based on Newtonsoft and AutoMapper they will choose A.

Comment: This seems to be the best way to handle this.

Comment: Frequently the naming convention for this setup is `MyCompany.MyProduct.dll` for part A and `MyCompany.MyProduct.Core.dll` for part B.